# Run a Job in ALL distributed server instances

Tags: hangfire

Today we are using HangFire to distribute the load between different servers, and works ok with BackgroundJob.Enqueue()

But I need a way to run a Job in all Hangfire servers such as the following

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => refreshCachedVariables());
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As far as I know, Hangfire is not designed to achieve this goal